# OAUTH 2.0 Authorization Code flow and API key in Authorization header

Tags: spring, rest, oauth-2.0, jwt, api-key

We are creating `Spring Boot` REST services that registered third parties can use.

- We provided the third parties with a unique API key in `JWT` format, containing authorizations for that party to the services it can use.
- The `JWT` is securely provided to the third parties and they need to include it in their requests to our API in the Authorization: Bearer header.

There exists new a use case where our API needs to call an other party's `OAUTH2` authorized services. They probably are going to use the `OAUTH2.0` Authorization Code Flow. This means that the third parties that are calling our API need to be redirected to the Authorization server of the other party to authenticate and get an `oauth` token generated.

**Questions**

The question/problem that we have now is, can we refactor our `JWT` token to include the oauth token from the other party?

And how will the flow look like then?

Or should we proceed with 2 different headers and store our API key `JWT` token in another header then the Authorization header?